# psql: FATAL: role "root" does not exist when creating database from fabric explorer's sql file

Tags: postgresql, centos, hyperledger-explorer

I meet error `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist` when running `./createdb.sh` from `https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer`. I am trying to run the blockchain explorer on Centos.

Comment: your question should more details.

Comment: This question lacks detail, but it looks like a MySQL script run against PostgreSQL, which doesn't work so well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last version broke something, or makes it incompatible with some of the tooling around.

Try reverting to the prev docker images: 
hyperledger/explorer-db:0.3.8
hyperledger/explorer:0.3.8

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error for me  "psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist" when running the createdb.sh script. I am trying to install on ubuntu.

I fixed it by running the following command before :

/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/bin$ createuser -s postgres

than run the createdb.sh script WITHOUT using sudo.

Hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify the DB user while running the script.

Modify `explorerconfig.json` under `blockchain-explorer/app` to include the properties of the connection to DB like "host", "port", "database", "username" and "password".

Please refer to this readme from their github repo - https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/README.md#Database-Setup